# How can I create a secondary database to run alongside my MediaWiki server?

Tags: mysql, database, mediawiki

Firstly, my aim is to create a database to store statistical information about my wiki articles, that is derived using extensions that I have written for my MediaWiki server. Then via another extension on my server, I wish to access this secondary database and use the information to edit the output of the final article page.

I wanted to try and make a separate database to avoid introducing errors to the existing MediaWiki schema. Is this possible? I can't find any information about running an additional mySQL database alongside a MediaWiki installation.

I feel as though the better solution may be to add a table to the existing schema, but I'm not sure how to deal with the existing infrastructure without breaking it. I believe I can just use standard CREATE commands but mySQL is unfortunately not my strong point.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hope i understood your problem. say you have media wiki server or a mysql server running on port 3308 and you want to create another mysql instance.
Follow this step:

`bkp my.cnf file`

`start first instance on port 3308`

`chnage my.cnf settings & make it run on 3307`

`start second instance of mysql`

If you have good h/w,swap/RAM, you can easily create such 4-5 instances & all will be running good.

Comment: Thanks, this is essentially what I was trying to accomplish but given Christian's comment above I think adding tables to the existing database is probably a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a separate database along with the primary MediaWiki database. You just have to open a connection to it specifically using the [PHP MySQL API](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php).

Adding a new table to the existing database though is really easy and probably your best bet. You will be able to take advantage of the built-in database load balancing if your site ever gets big. To learn how to create a new table from an extension, check out [this page of documentation](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aHooks/LoadExtensionSchemaUpdates).

Comment: Thanks, that page of documentation looks fantastic, exactly what I was after but couldn't find! I'll have a good look through that and get to work, doesn't look like I'll have too much trouble with that information.

Thanks again.